# Delete all emails from Exchange 2007 account

Tags: email, exchange-server, windows-sbs

We have an overweight an bloated email account on Exchange 2007 running on a SBS 2008 which needs emptying, but not deleting.  unfortunately there was no monitoring in place and now it's slowing the entire network down (another long story)...

What would be the easiest and most efficient way to remove all emails from the offending email account please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to grant access and setup shell scripts in Exchange Management Shell. Just use these shell commands to make your job easier. 
http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/892-delete-emails-in-exchange-2007